# Video Compression using ffpmeg

Tags: android, android-ffmpeg

I am using ffmeg for video compression. I have used [ffpmeg library](http://com.madhavanmalolan.android:ffmpegandroidlibrary:0.0.4)

Use command `"ffmpeg -i " + filein.trim() + " -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 " + fileout.trim()` but i doesn't respond anything.

I have used any ndk library for first time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command will work for you. This works for me .

```
String cmd = "-y -i " + currentInputVideoPath + " -strict -2 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast " + "-crf 24 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 96k -s 320x240 -aspect 4:3 " + currentOutputVideoPath;
```

Comment: It is not working for me Is the problem with library i have used?

Comment: No . library has not such a problem.

Comment: try to debug to find out its cause

Comment: I have used only single line  String[] Controller.getInstance().run(command); and there is no other method how to i make a debug.

Comment: Use this Demo with your ffmpeg command.`https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java`